# Appropriate to ask question regarding choice of "magma" to describe simple algebraic structures?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I just started reading Bourbaki's Algebra, and [posed a question regarding the choice of the word "magma" (which I came across on the first page of Bourbaki) on History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/from-the-perspective-of-etymology-why-was-the-word-magma-chosen-to-describe-a).

I am thinking that professional mathematicians who are in the "cultural know" might be able to give me an answer that isn't pure speculation. In any case, would it be okay to ask such a question on MO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specific question should be closed as a duplicate of [What is the origin of the term magma?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103128/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-magma)

Moreover, you already got a link to an answer on English.SE provided by a professional mathematician; the question on English being answered by two  professional mathematicians (or perhaps technically one mathematician and one theoretical computer scientist).

Finally, you should wait a bit longer than half-a-day on a new a slow paced site like HSM.SE before looking for other options.

Thus, while in principle such questions can be on-topic on MO to ask your question now is inappropriate for several reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about the history of mathematical terminology have generally been well-received on MO in the past ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/terminology+ho.history-overview) are some examples, and there are probably more that don't have those tags).  I would consider your question on-topic.